# Flutter cannot connect to flet server when creating a flutter project with serious python

Tags: python, flutter, flet

I am trying to make my python flet project into an apk by first turning it into a flutter project with serious python, I keep getting the error:

> "Error connecting to Flet server: SocketException: Connection failed
> (OS Error: No such file or directory, errno = 2), address = flet.sock,
> port = 0".

Originally, I was using a complicated flet project where there were many variables that could've gone wrong. I tried with a simple flet project, yet I get the same issue. This does not occur when I run a flutter project originally made in dart.